# CoreOS auto update, but which channel (Alpha, Beta, Stable)?

Tags: coreos

CoreOS was with the beta channel:

```
coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C beta -c ./cloud-config.yaml
```

SSH into the CoreOS host, and check the version:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release

NAME=CoreOS
ID=coreos
VERSION=991.2.0
VERSION_ID=991.2.0
BUILD_ID=2016-03-26-0329
PRETTY_NAME="CoreOS 991.2.0 (Coeur Rouge)"
ANSI_COLOR="1;32"
HOME_URL="https://coreos.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues"
```

**Question 1**: How frequent CoreOS checks for update? Would it continue within the same [Release Channel](https://coreos.com/releases/)?

**Question 2**: Is the Release Channel information (which was used to install CoreOS) written somewhere on the CoreOS host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks for an update roughly every hour. You can verify this with `journalctl -u update-engine` to watch the logs.

Correct, the channel is stored in `/etc/coreos/update.conf`

Comment: Thanks. https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html shows that in cloud-config, there is a setting coreos.update.group which can take values “master”, “alpha”, “beta”, “stable”. Can you tell me what would happen if that config setting has a different value than the one in /etc/coreos/update.conf? Let's say because I play around with cloud-config and forgot to keep update.conf in sync.

Comment: Cloud-init (the thing that processes your cloud-config) will write/update the value in `/etc/coreos/update.conf`, so keeping your cloud-config up to date is all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [Switching Release Channels](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/switching-channels.html) It seems that the information is written in `/etc/coreos/update.conf`
In my case. The content of that file is:

```
$ cat /etc/coreos/update.conf

GROUP=beta
REBOOT_STRATEGY=reboot
```

I suppose this answers Q2. But how about the frequency CoreOS checks for update?